# Can I transfer google play data to another gmail account address?

Tags: google-account, google-play-services, data-transfer

I have been using other people google account for my google play. When I create my own google account, can I transfer every data (example: game account that bind to the google play) from the previous google account to my new google account?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. However for games, based on this [answer](https://support.google.com/googleplay/thread/5053822?hl=en):

> the answer is it depends "on how the game data is saved by the developer"  For most games, no, you can't move their progress from one account to another.  But, some games do have that ability.
>
> You'll have to check with the developer of each game directly to see if they have coded that ability for their game.  Google doesn't have an overarching way to move data.